# Adding a column in Entity Framework Core migration to a table previously populated with HasData

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm using .NET Entity Framework Core with database migrations and the Fluent API in a .NET 6 application. (I'm away from the network where my work is, so this simplified version is off the top of my head; please don't quibble about syntax goofs. The real code builds and I was able to generate a migration.) I have a model class:

```
public class Foo
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

and then, in the database context,

```
public DbSet<Foo> Foos => Set<Foo>();

// and later, in OnModelCreating
var foo = modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>();
foo.HasKey(f => f.Id);
foo.HasProperty(f => f.Id).IsRequired();
foo.HasProperty(f => f.Name).IsRequired();
foo.HasData(new Foo { Id = 1, Name = "Apple" });
foo.HasData(new Foo { Id = 2, Name = "Banana" });
```

In my latest update I added a column, Quantity.

```
public class Foo
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
  public in Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

and wanted to add the column to the existing data:

```
var foo = modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>();
foo.HasKey(f => f.Id);
foo.HasProperty(f => f.Id).IsRequired();
foo.HasProperty(f => f.Name).IsRequired();
foo.HasProperty(f => f.Quantity).IsRequired();
foo.HasData(new Foo { Id = 1, Name = "Apple", Quantity = 6 });
foo.HasData(new Foo { Id = 2, Name = "Banana", Quantity = 9 });
```

But instead of adding the column and then setting the Quantity values on the existing rows, it tried to delete the rows--which it couldn't do because another table's foreign key references Foo.Id--and insert new ones.

Is there a way using the Fluent API doing what I want? Or should I go into the migration I generated and fix it somehow in the Up method? And figure out the corresponding change I should make for the Down method?